# Why should this first post (first answer) be flagged VLQ? (disputed review audit)

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

When I reviewed the following answer with an upvote (to be followed by a comment asking the poster to elaborate more) I was slapped on the wrist because I should have downvoted and/or flagged VLQ.

I disagree. The answer certainly should elaborate and copy enough text from the links that the answer is still clear if the links die but the essence of the answer is there. The poster explained where to look and gave an example of what to use. It might not be a great answer and could definitely be improved upon but it looks moderately okay and with some stimulation for the poster might become even better.

Am I wrong in my assessment? How should I handle such audits where I disagree? All I could find was to post it on meta.

[image: review audit]

Edit: link to review https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14105663

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if you gave a link to the review, question, and/or answer.

Comment: related to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).  There are a lot of things that get flagged and deleted that really should not be.  Looks like this was one of them.  While the answer is not the greatest IMHO it is not flag worthy and if it needs to be removed down votes and delete votes are the way to handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the answer may well be of low quality, but it is not "Not an Answer".  While a reader may feel it merits a downvote for providing an inadequate explanation, it certainly isn't lacking an explanation *entirely*, which would have to be the case to merit deletion.

In a case such as this you can flag the post for moderator attention to indiate that you feel the post has been inappropriately deleted, and explain why.  (And if you have 20k rep, you could vote to undelete.)

Comment: Unfortunately, my rep is stil too low and I can't see the deleted answer and therefore can't raise a flag for moderator attention on it (and I can't raise a flag from the review link either). 

Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @Buurman In those cases you can flag one of your own posts or the question and explain what is going on.

Comment: @Buurman Just flag the question.

Comment: @Buurman - Here's the review that led to it being deleted: http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13900406 . Six people apparently thought it should be, which led to the deletion and validation of the flag. At that point, it became an audit. I disagree with the review, so I've undeleted the answer to remove it as an audit case. You're not the only one to be tripped up by this.

Comment: @BradLarson look at all those people, "doing it wrong", maybe a plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts Review queue is in order. Wait a minute....

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments all, and thanks for fixing it @BradLarson